# Is there a way to create GLX context after Xlib's window creation?

Tags: linux, opengl, window, xlib

I'm trying to create OpenGLx context after the Xlib's window creation. I'm trying to separate the Xlib window creation and opengl context creation into two different phases.
Win32 window-opengl context creation was rather simple but I couldnt find any resource that illustrates the same process with Xlib-opengl in linux

This is how its done for xlib-linux

```
GLint glxAttribs[] = {
    GLX_RGBA,
    GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,
    GLX_DEPTH_SIZE,     24,
    GLX_STENCIL_SIZE,   8,
    GLX_RED_SIZE,       8,
    GLX_GREEN_SIZE,     8,
    GLX_BLUE_SIZE,      8,
    GLX_SAMPLE_BUFFERS, 0,
    GLX_SAMPLES,        0,
    None
};


XVisualInfo* visual = glXChooseVisual(display, screenId, glxAttribs);
XSetWindowAttributes windowAttribs;
windowAttribs.border_pixel = BlackPixel(display, screenId);
windowAttribs.background_pixel = WhitePixel(display, screenId);
windowAttribs.override_redirect = True;
windowAttribs.colormap = XCreateColormap(display, RootWindow(display, screenId), visual->visual, AllocNone);
windowAttribs.event_mask = ExposureMask;
window = XCreateWindow(display, RootWindow(display, screenId), 0, 0, 320, 200, 0, visual->depth, InputOutput, visual->visual, CWBackPixel | CWColormap | CWBorderPixel | CWEventMask, &windowAttribs);
```

This is how its done in windows

```
const WindowsWindow* pWin32Window = (const WindowsWindow*)pOwnerWindow;

        HWND windowHandle = pWin32Window->GetWin32WindowHandle();
        HDC windowDeviceContext = pWin32Window->GetWin32WindowDeviceContext();

        /*
        * Create pixel format
        */
        PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR pfd = { sizeof(pfd),1 };
        memset(&pfd, 0, sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR));
        pfd.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
        pfd.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER;
        pfd.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
        pfd.nVersion = 1;
        pfd.cColorBits = OpenGLDeviceUtilsWin32::GetColorBits(desc.SwapchainBufferFormat);
        pfd.cAlphaBits = OpenGLDeviceUtilsWin32::GetAlphaBits(desc.SwapchainBufferFormat);
        pfd.cDepthBits = OpenGLDeviceUtilsWin32::GetDepthBits(desc.SwapchainDepthStencilBufferFormat);
        pfd.cStencilBits = OpenGLDeviceUtilsWin32::GetStencilBits(desc.SwapchainDepthStencilBufferFormat);
        pfd.cAuxBuffers = 3;
        pfd.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;

        const int pixelFormatIndex = ChoosePixelFormat(windowDeviceContext, &pfd);
        ASSERT(pixelFormatIndex != 0,"OpenGLDevice","Invalid pixel format");

        ASSERT(SetPixelFormat(windowDeviceContext, pixelFormatIndex, &pfd), "OpenGLDevice", "Win32 window rejected the specified pixel format");

        HGLRC tempContext = wglCreateContext(windowDeviceContext);
        ASSERT(tempContext != NULL, "OpenGLDevice", "Creation of wgl dummy context failed!");

        wglMakeCurrent(windowDeviceContext, tempContext);

        PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC wglCreateContextAttribsARB = NULL;
        wglCreateContextAttribsARB = (PFNWGLCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)wglGetProcAddress("wglCreateContextAttribsARB");
        ASSERT(wglCreateContextAttribsARB != NULL, "OpenGLDevice", "WGL get proc address failed!");
```

But I would expect something like this.

- Create xlib window
- Check for glx attribs if the window can support that pixel format
- Create glx context using pixel format

But instead it goes as

- Create window with your specific glx attribs
- Create glx context

I wonder if there is a way for us to create window without letting xlib know we are going to use it for opengl and implement OpenGL specific setup for window creation process.

Comment: > _Win32 window-opengl context creation_
What do you mean by that? Are you assuming any specific source code and related links with these words?

Comment: And what do you mean by **_separate_** in your question? Creating XWindow and creating OpenGL Context (== GLX Context) with it are usually executed separately. BTW, what do you think about this [link](https://github.com/gamedevtech/X11OpenGLWindow)? That link is rather old, but will be helpful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, I do not understand your motivation.

Many implementations like GLFW gets `Visual` from GLX/EGL APIs (including glXChooseFBConfig) and use it when creating a window. The GLX/EGL stuff part can be abstracted by writing wrappers, so I don't see the need to go to the trouble of avoiding it.

That being said, it is still possible to avoid it, so I wrote the sample code for you.

```cpp
// To build, execute the command below.
// c++ -Wall -Wextra -std=c++17 -o main main.cpp -lX11 -lGLX -lGL

#include <cstdio>

#include <chrono>
#include <thread>

#include <sys/time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <X11/Xutil.h>
#include <GL/glx.h>
#include <GL/glxext.h>

#define OGL_MAJOR_VERSION 3
#define OGL_MINOR_VERSION 3

#define WINDOW_WIDTH 640
#define WINDOW_HEIGHT 360
#define FPS 60

static double get_time() {
    static timeval s_tTimeVal;
    gettimeofday(&s_tTimeVal, NULL);
    double time = s_tTimeVal.tv_sec * 1000.0; // sec to ms
    time += s_tTimeVal.tv_usec / 1000.0;      // us to ms
    return time;
}

struct TestWindowConfig {
    int width = 640;
    int height = 360;
};

class TestWindow final {
  public:
    explicit TestWindow(const TestWindowConfig& config) : m_config(config) {}
    virtual ~TestWindow() {
        if (m_display) {
            if (m_xid) {
                XDestroyWindow(m_display, m_xid);
            }
            XCloseDisplay(m_display);
        }
    }

    bool create() {
        m_display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
        if (!m_display) {
            fprintf(stderr, "XOpenDisplay() failed\n");
            return false;
        }

        XSetWindowAttributes x_attr;
        x_attr.override_redirect = False;
        x_attr.border_pixel = 0;

        m_xid = XCreateWindow(m_display, DefaultRootWindow(m_display), 0, 0, m_config.width,
                              m_config.height, 0, CopyFromParent, InputOutput, CopyFromParent,
                              CWOverrideRedirect | CWBorderPixel, &x_attr);
        if (!m_xid) {
            fprintf(stderr, "XOpenDisplay() failed\n");
            return false;
        }
        XStoreName(m_display, m_xid, "X11-GLX Sample");
        XMapWindow(m_display, m_xid);

        m_wm_delete_window = XInternAtom(m_display, "WM_DELETE_WINDOW", True);
        XSetWMProtocols(m_display, m_xid, &m_wm_delete_window, 1);

        return true;
    }

    void show() const {
        if (m_display && m_xid) {
            XMapRaised(m_display, m_xid);
        }
    }

    bool poll_events() {
        if (!m_display) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Display is null\n");
            return false;
        }

        while (XPending(m_display) > 0) {
            XEvent ev;
            XNextEvent(m_display, &ev);
            if (ev.type == ClientMessage) {
                if ((Atom)ev.xclient.data.l[0] == m_wm_delete_window) {
                    m_should_close = true;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
    }

    bool should_close() const { return m_should_close; }

    Display* display() const { return m_display; }

    Window xid() const { return m_xid; }

    int screen_id() const { return DefaultScreen(m_display); }

  private:
    TestWindowConfig m_config;
    Display* m_display = nullptr;
    Window m_xid = 0;
    Atom m_wm_delete_window;

    bool m_should_close = false;
};

class TestGLContext final {
  public:
    explicit TestGLContext() = default;

    virtual ~TestGLContext() = default;

    bool create(const TestWindow& window) {
        // clang-format off
        int visual_attr[] = {
            GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_WINDOW_BIT,
            GLX_RENDER_TYPE,   GLX_RGBA_BIT,
            GLX_RED_SIZE,      8,
            GLX_GREEN_SIZE,    8,
            GLX_BLUE_SIZE,     8,
            GLX_ALPHA_SIZE,    8,
            GLX_DEPTH_SIZE,    0,
            GLX_STENCIL_SIZE,  0,
            GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER,  True,
            None
        };
        // clang-format on
        int cfg_count;
        auto fb_configs =
            glXChooseFBConfig(window.display(), window.screen_id(), visual_attr, &cfg_count);
        if (!fb_configs || (cfg_count < 1)) {
            fprintf(stderr, "glXChooseFBConfig(): No config found\n");
            return false;
        }
        PFNGLXCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC glXCreateContextAttribsARB =
            (PFNGLXCREATECONTEXTATTRIBSARBPROC)glXGetProcAddressARB(
                (const GLubyte*)"glXCreateContextAttribsARB");
        if (!glXCreateContextAttribsARB) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load glXCreateContextAttribsARB\n");
            return false;
        }
        // clang-format off
        int ctx_attr[] = {
            GLX_CONTEXT_PROFILE_MASK_ARB,  GLX_CONTEXT_CORE_PROFILE_BIT_ARB,
            GLX_CONTEXT_MAJOR_VERSION_ARB, OGL_MAJOR_VERSION,
            GLX_CONTEXT_MINOR_VERSION_ARB, OGL_MINOR_VERSION,
            0, 0
        };
        // clang-format on
        m_ctx = glXCreateContextAttribsARB(window.display(), fb_configs[0], NULL, True, ctx_attr);
        if (!m_ctx) {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to create GLX Context\n");
            return false;
        }

        m_should_destroy = true;

        return true;
    }

    bool make_current(const TestWindow& window) {
        if (glXMakeCurrent(window.display(), window.xid(), m_ctx) != True) {
            fprintf(stderr, "glXMakeCurrent() Failed\n");
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    void swap_buffers(const TestWindow& window) { glXSwapBuffers(window.display(), window.xid()); }

    static void* get_proc_address(const char* name) {
        return reinterpret_cast<void*>(glXGetProcAddress((const GLubyte*)name));
    }

    void destroy(const TestWindow& window) {
        glXDestroyContext(window.display(), m_ctx);
        m_should_destroy = false;
    }

    bool should_destroy() const { return m_should_destroy; }

  private:
    GLXContext m_ctx;

    bool m_should_destroy = false;
};

int main() {
    // 1. Prepare Window and OpenGL Context
    // In normal design, TestWindow should have its GLContext within itself.
    // But, in order to fit your needs, I separated these explicitly.

    TestWindowConfig config{.width = WINDOW_WIDTH, .height = WINDOW_HEIGHT};
    TestWindow window{config};
    TestGLContext glctx{};

    if (!window.create()) {
        return 1;
    }

    if (!glctx.create(window) || !glctx.make_current(window)) {
        if (glctx.should_destroy()) {
            glctx.destroy(window);
        }
        return 1;
    }

    // 2. Load OpenGL functions
    // In normal cases, you are always recommended to use loader libraries like glad.
    // In this example, I omited the loading part.
    //
    // if (!gladLoadGLLoader((GLADloadproc)glctx.get_proc_address)) {
    //     fprintf(stderr, "Failed to load OpenGL functions\n");
    //     return 1;
    // }

    // 3. Show the window and call OpenGL APIs
    // As above, there are various problems in this implentation for real use.
    window.show();

    double last_time = get_time();
    while (true) {
        if (!window.poll_events() || window.should_close()) {
            break;
        }

        auto delta_ms = get_time() - last_time;
        if (auto diff = (1000.0 / FPS) - delta_ms; diff > 0) {
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds((long)diff));
            continue;
        }
        // fprintf(stderr, "delta: %f\n", delta_ms);

        glViewport(0, 0, config.width, config.height);
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        glctx.swap_buffers(window);

        last_time = get_time();
    }

    glctx.destroy(window);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to create OpenGLx context after the Xlib's window creation.

I don't really see your problem. On Win32 the usual stanza is:

1. Create window
2. Select pixelformat
3. Set pixelformat on window
4. Get HDC from window and use it to create context

On GLX the stanza is:

1. Select visual for window
2. Create window that's compatible with visual
3. Create OpenGL context with the selected visual

Take note that in **both** Win32 and GLX there is no hard tie between the window and the OpenGL context. As long as the pixelformat/visual of a OpenGL context and a window are compatiple, you can use them with each other.

The only difference between GLX and Win32 is, how the pixelformat/visual is communicated to OpenGL context creation. In GLX it's done directy, in Win32 the pixelformat is communicated in a rather convoluted way by means of the HDC of a window. And take note that in order to obtain a modern OpenGL context you actually have to go the route of OpenGL context creation with attributes which works ***exactly*** the same in Win32 and GLX (with Win32 needing the added steps of creating a dummy OpenGL context first in order to obtain the function pointers to the `wglCreateContextAttribsARB` functions, which are directly available in GLX).